# Consider a reflection as an element of the permutation group of the vertices of a regular (2n + 1)-gon. Is the permutation even or odd?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, dihedral-groups, permutation-cycles

Let $n \ge 1$ be an integer. Let $F \in D_{(2n+1)}$ be a reflection. Consider $F$ as an element of the permutation group of the vertices of a regular $(2n + 1)$-gon. Is this permutation even or odd?

My thinking is that the permutation would be even since if you have a permutation of odd order, then that permutation can be written as the product of an even number of two-cycles.

For example, if $\sigma = (1234)(57)$ in $S_7$, then $\sigma$ can be written as the product of 2-cycles, $(14)(13)(12)(57)$ Since $\sigma$ can be written as the product of an even number of 2-cycles, we conclude that it's an even permutation.

So, for this question, we're dealing with a polygon with an odd number of vertices and sides. $D_{(2n+1)}$ has $2n+1$ rotations and $2n+1$ reflections. Since the number of reflections is odd, doesn't that imply that they can be written as the product of an even number of 2-cycles? Or am I misinterpreting the question?

Any assistance would be most appreciated.

Kindest Regards

Comment: Do yourself a favor. Take n=3. Draw a 7gon. Number the vertices. Write down the permutation of those vertices induced by a reflection. Write it as a product of transpositions.

Comment: Or take $n=1$ or $n=2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

If there's *one* answer,  the easiest would be to just look at a triangle.   In that case two of the points get interchanged, one staying fixed.  That implies a single transposition,  and so odd order.

But to verify try a couple slightly more complicated examples. Yep.  When I try a regular pentagon,  I get reflection as a product of two transpositions.   So even.

The pattern is easy to see. It's even when $n$ is even;   odd when $n$ is odd.

That's if you draw a line through one point and split the opposite side,  you then have $n$ pairs to interchange..  So $n$ transpositions.